# Mono For Android- bluetooth Connect does not end

Tags: android, mono, bluetooth

I created solution for bluetooth connection to datamax printer (APEX 4). I do not use threads, it simple "fire-and-forget" task.

```
mSocket=device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);                                                                                              
                    mAdapter.CancelDiscovery();                     
                    mSocket.Connect();
```

UUID is default 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb.

Problem is that calling Connect does not end- there is no exception, it just hangs :(
In ouput appears only :

D/BluetoothSocket(12234): create BluetoothSocket: type = 1, fd = -1, uuid = [00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb], port = -1

I am testing on Samsung Galaxy S Plus. Any clues?